# Why am I getting an Error Parsing JSON Response with this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, spotify

When making a POST request to the Spotify API using https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js I keep getting back a 400 bad request with the response "Error Parsing JSON'

The JSON from the request headers looks valid to me.

```
{"uris":"spotify:track:5qmq61DAAOUaW8AUo8xKhh"}


const addTrackToPlaylist = (track) => {
    spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist('4EiIrcKLn4P7xdHOj6tZ9Y', `spotify:track:${track}`)
    .then( (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I should get back a 201 and not the 400.

Comment: It means your API transaction was unsuccessful, check the details returned by the request.

Comment: `{"uris": ["spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh","spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M"]}`

Did you try passing it in as an object formed like the above?

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/add-tracks-to-playlist/

Comment: Yeah the JSON at the top was the payload that was sent to the API. I see the difference though but I'm just trying to pass a single song not an array of songs.

Answer (score 1):

The `addTracksToPlaylist` from `spotify-web-api-js` takes in an array of spotify uri's even if it is only 1 track.

You would need to update your request to include the track in an array:

```
spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist('4EiIrcKLn4P7xdHOj6tZ9Y', [`spotify:track:${track}`])
```

See https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js/blob/master/src/spotify-web-api.js#L779